# Function cannot run concurrently

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to make a function that only run once and cancel if is still running.

I tried it using a simple lock boolean on start/end, but sometimes it's "overlapping".

There's a better and secure way to do that?

---

```
@property (assign) BOOL lock;

- (void)myFuntion
{
    if (self.lock) {
        NSLog(@"(Canceled) Syncing is already running...");
        return;
    }

    self.lock = YES;

    // My Code

    self.lock = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSLock` class should be able to help you here. I have not tried this example directly, but something like:

```
NSLock *myFunctionLock=[NSLock new]; // this should be a class data member/property/etc.

- (void)myFuntion
{
    if (![myFunctionLock tryLock])
        return; /* already running */

    // My Synchronized Code

    [myFunctionLock unlock];
}
```

Comment: But the OP wants the 2nd attempt to simply return, not block and wait.

Comment: @mah In that case, functionally, theres any difference using a `BOOL` (like the original) or `NSLock`?

Comment: @LucianoNascimento the difference is that while the way you did it (which doesn't matter if its a BOOL or any other variable type) has a potential race condition (due to the ability for a thread to suspend after checking but before setting the variable), using the operating system provided lock does not (at the expense of a little extra overhead). The safety is exactly why you want to use a greater overhead tool like `NSLock` instead of a simple variable.

Answer (score 1):

We are all assuming that you are talking about concurrent programming, where you are running the same code on different threads. If that's not what you mean then you would need to explain what you DO mean, since code that runs on the same thread can only  execute a function once at any particular moment.

Take a look at `NSLock`'s `tryLock` function. The first caller to assert the lock gets back a TRUE, and can proceed to access the critical resource. Other callers get back FALSE and should not access the critical resource, but won't block.